# Join two cell in a numpy.ndarray into a single cell

Tags: arrays, numpy, join

I have a np array with two cells (0,0) and (1,0) with strings in them, let's call them 'A' and 'B'. how can i join them together into a single cell (0,0) with value 'A' 'B'?
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
np.array([your_array[0,0] + " " + your_array[1,0]])
```